# Curiosity about 'total reputation' and 'reputation change' table

Tags: discussion

This is a mere curiosity, but I looked at the reputation tables and saw the following:

[image]

Are these mere coincidences?

E.g. the *total* number of users with 5,000+ reputation is exactly the same as the ones having had a reputation *change* of 5,000+. Have they all started at 0?

Pardon the quick and not-aligned rectangles on Paint...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking at the [all time leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/151/alltime/physics). The 'Reputation Change' you see there is the reputation change since the beginning of the site, so it's expected that that number matches.

When you look at the [weekly league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/151/week/physics), you'll see that the 'Total Reputation' stays the same but the 'Reputation Change' is different:

[image]